# SDcard in lollipop still readonly using EZPDF

Tags: sd-card, 5.1-lollipop, permissions

I finally got my lollipop upgrade. Seemed fine but I have still issues with EZPDF. Let me explain.

I just upgraded from kitkat and therefore, I cannot write to the SD card as we all know. After the upgrade, two of my apps "File Expert" and "MX Player Pro" asked me to grant access to the SD card. I did and both work fine.

The issue is with EZPDF. I cannot find any way to grant the same permission in order to be allowed to write an annotated PDF into the SD card. The file list still marks the SD files as "Read only".

Any hint?

I really appreciate any advise with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the new Lollipop update allows apps to write to SD Card, it requires the user to grant the apps access, like you've stated above.

For apps to gain access they have to call the new API introduce in the   lollipop which allows user to grant app permissions.For the apps to call this API, the devloper of the apps have to write code into their app to do this.

As I was saying above, the devloper needs to write some code to do this, for which the particular app you want to grant the access SD Card does not have.

I am sure that their are ways to forceable do this, of which I don't know of, that would probably require root, phone modification and technical know how to do.

Comment: Hi Matt. As I said and you agree, the issue is with the provider of tha app. I had been wating fot their answer for over a week and nothing yet. Maybe is time to get another app. Looks like xodo has the same features.

Comment: @notuo, Sorry I wasnt any more help, but this is a problem only the devloper of the app can fix so you will either need to use a different app or just put up with the missing functionality